# Is it possible to set the scroll view to Toast message when it has content of more than a specific length?

Tags: angular, charts, tooltip, angular-chart

[image: Angular ngx-chart toast message]
I like to show scroll in toast message which has length exceeding 10 rows
Note: Trying to add in Angular Ngx-chart https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/